# How to scroll to and focus an EditText inside a view in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Each item in my RecyclerView contains several views including an EditText. In response to user action, I want to scroll to a specific position in RecyclerView and focus the corresponding EditText.
I can scroll to the position:

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

and get the ViewHolder of that position

```
RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
```

and then find that EditText in the view of viewHolder and do the rest.

The problem is that, when target position is not visible, `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition` returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found a workaround:
When the view is visible, it could be accessed using `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition`. Otherwise you have to scroll to its position. But you have to add an `OnScrollListener` before doing so. When layout update is done and scrolling finished, the view is accessible using `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition`.
`OnScrollListener` could be something like this:

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

    if (newState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
        /*
            find the view and focus on it here.
        */
        recyclerView.removeOnScrollListener(this);
    }
}
```